# How to get the path of word file from current folder without need to change path when running on some other machine in c#

Tags: c#, highlight

Here is my code.

How can I run the EXE on any machine without changing the path?

```
    object fileName=  @"Sam.docx"; //The filepath goes her
           //The text to find goes here

    Word.Application word = new Word.Application();
    Word.Document doc = new Word.Document();
    string line;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // int counter = 0;


        System.IO.FileStream stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetFile(@"Sample.txt");
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
        new System.IO.StreamReader(@"Sample.txt");
        //object matchWholeWord = true;

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            // Define an object to pass to the API for missing parameters
            object missing = System.Type.Missing;
            doc = word.Documents.Open(ref   fileName,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            string ReadValue = string.Empty;
            // Activate the document
            doc.Activate();
```

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the title of this posting: *"How to get the path of word file from current folder"*

---

Use the following property to retrieve the directory of where your application (*.exe) is executing from:`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

**BE ADVISED**

The `Environment.CurrentDirectory` property can be misleading as will not always return the *current directory* as you would expect.  For example, `Environment.CurrentDirectory` will not return your application's *.exe directory if your application is running as a Windows service.

**REFERENCES**

- [AppDomain.BaseDirectory Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)